# Mersenne primes: All even and perfect number has the form $2^{p-1}M_p$ for some prime $p$, being $M_p$ a prime of Mersenne.

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

All even and perfect number has the form $2^{p-1}M_p$ for some prime $p$, being $M_p$ a prime of Mersenne.

What I did was:

Suppose that $n = 2^kb$ and $\sigma(n) = 2n$. Then, $\sigma(2^kb) = (2^{k+1} - 1)\sigma(b).$
But then, once $\sigma(2n) = 2^{k+1}b$ we get that:
$$2^{k+1}b = (2^{k+1} - 1)\sigma(b).$$
Even more, $\gcd(2^{k+1},2^{k+1} - 1) = 1.$
Then, $b = (2^{k+1} - 1)c,$ for some $c \in \mathbb{N}.$

I can't follow from here. Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Any other approach is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there! If we can prove that $b$ has exactly two divisors, then we're done because we know that $c$ must be $1$ and that $b$ must be prime.

Indeed, you showed that we have
$$
2^{k+1} b = 2^{k+1} (2^{k+1} - 1) c = (2^{k+1} - 1) \sigma(b)
$$
therefore
$$
2^{k+1} c = \sigma(b) = b + c + \textit{stuff} = (2^{k+1} - 1) c + c + \textit{stuff} = 2^{k+1} c + \textit{stuff}
$$
It follows that $\textit{stuff} = 0$, i.e. that there are no divisors of $b$ other than $c$ and $b$ itself.

Comment: Nice!!!! thanks a lot @A.P. !